# java .app packaged with java jpackage cannot save file to the file system on a mac

Tags: java, jpackage

I have a simple java application that is packaged with jpackage into a hello.app on a Mac. I am trying to write a file to the user home directory. Getting the following error: `(Read-only file system)`.  The app works fine on Windows. If I run the program from the IDE or the jlink version then it works fine but .app package does not because it is trying to write to the root directory. Why is the path different when I run the .app vs the jlink image?

I've tried `System.getProperty("user.home")`. Also, I tried using  `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`. Neither one of them worked.

Comment: **Never** use getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().  getCodeSource() may return null.  Even if it doesn’t, getLocation() may return null.  Even if it doesn’t, the getPath() method of URL does not return a valid filename—it’s just the URL-encoded path portion of a URL.  System.getProperty("user.home") should have worked;  consider editing your question and showing us the code that used it.

Comment: thank you very  much for the reply. System.getProperty("user.home") worked.

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem? Are there files need to be saved outside .app package directory?

Answer (score 0):

You have giving the access to Java permission on your macOS. See this https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2020/20200119_1427-macOS-Catalina-add-java-fullDiskAccess.html